# Single Machine Sequencing - Optimize an oven schedule with expiring products

Tags: algorithm, math, schedule

Let's say you own a burrito restaurant and you need to cook beef, chicken, and shrimp on the grill for the lunch rush. You know how much of each item you will need to have prepared and ready to serve at any given 15 minute interval (i.e. 12:00 to 12:15, 12:15 to 12:30, etc) based on historical demand.

Four more assumptions:

1. it takes each item a certain amount of time to cook (let's say 15 minutes for each)
2. The grill has a fixed capacity
3. you can only cook one item at any given time (for food safety reasons)
4. and **each item expires/goes bad an hour after cooking**.

If you know A) how much of each item you need during each time interval, B) how long it takes each item to cook, and C) how many units of each item you can fit on the grill at once, does an algorithm exist that outputs the schedule for cooking that will provide enough of each item to satisfy demand for every interval and minimizes waste?

Comment: If you have some beef on the grill, can you add some more beef at a later time, or would that be against 2? This sounds like some contest or exercise problem, can you give a reference where you found this?

Comment: You cannot add more beef at a later time, good question.This is not a contest or exercise problem, this is my job.

Comment: If demand is deterministic I don't think we need any waste. We can find a production schedule that meets exactly the demand without any spoilage. Of course if demand is stochastic things become different. Anyway it is not too difficult to develop a Mixed Integer Programming model  for this problem. Such models can be solved by readily available solvers.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, I am fairly certain there will be waste. If you are certain of the opposite, would you mind providing an explanation?

Comment: Say we have 15 minute periods. In period 1 cook beef for demand in periods 2,3,4. In period 2 cook chicken for demand in periods 3,4,5. In period 3 cook shrimp for demand in periods 4,5,6. In period 4 we do beef again: for demand in periods 5,6,7. etc.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, what happens if there were four items (let's say we added pork)?

Comment: Similar. In period 1 cook beef for demand in periods 2,3,4,5. etc. When adding even more items we will see periods without availability. But still no need for spoilage. You probably need to think the problem through a bit more.